# Convert list<int> to string flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

Lets say we have a list of integers:

```
List<int> integers=[4, 5];
```

I want to convert this List to string value like this:

```
String val="4,5"
```

How can I manage to do this in dart?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use join method to do so.

```
print(integers.join(","));
```

Answer (score 1):

The shortest answer is

`integers.join(',');`

If you want more control over the operation where let's say you want to do additional computation at each iteration you can use this:

```
  List<int> integers=[4, 5];

  StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
  for (int i = 0; i < integers.length; i++) {
    buffer.write(integers[i].toString() + ',');
  }
  //REMOVE LAST COMMA
  String values = '';
  if (integers.length > 0)
    values = buffer.toString().substring(0, buffer.length -1);
  print(values);
```

Comment: For performance reasons you should really use a `StringBuffer`in you last example to build the String since you are creating a lot of small String objects if the list is long: https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.8.0/dart-core/StringBuffer-class.html

Comment: @julemand101 thanks for the heads up. I've edited my answer and upvoted your comment

Comment: `StringBuffer` does has a length property so no reason to call toString twice just to get the length: https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.8.0/dart-core/StringBuffer/length.html